# Convert <object /> declaration to javascript ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I have the following  declaration in my code:

```
<object id="myObject" name="myObject" 
    data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,ab9qcMENN0WE41oij7hs8764yu+YEwAA2BMABB=="
    classid="clsid:83A04F76-85DF-4f36-A94E-BA3465007CDA" viewastext
    codebase="someAssembly.dll#version=UNKNOWN">
</object>
```

I want to create an instance of this same object, but inside a .js file, and so I'd like to construct this object without needing to use an  tag (if this is even possible):

```
var myObject = new ActiveXObject( *Something goes here* );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to create a new instance:

```
var newObj = new ActiveXObject(servername.typename[, location]);
```

As you can see there's an optional parameter `location` that you can use to access remote ActiveX objects but read details about it here:
[MSDN ActiveXObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28VS.85%29.aspx) (you'll find some info at the end of the document).

Answer (score -2):

You can access the "OBJECT" simply by calling it by its id. For instance:

```
<object id="myObject" name="myObject" 
    data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,ab9qcMENN0WE41oij7hs8764yu+YEwAA2BMABB=="
    classid="clsid:83A04F76-85DF-4f36-A94E-BA3465007CDA" viewastext
    codebase="someAssembly.dll#version=UNKNOWN">
</object>
```

Now, I can access it as follows:

```
myObject.userText = "hello!";
```

Where "userText" is a property of that object.

I hope this would answer your question.

Comment: Haven't Microsoft fixed the "Global JS objects for every element with an ID" bug yet?

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question at all BTW.

Comment: I'm afraid they do. I recently implement an activeX control which is a component instead of a control and I did the same calling by the OBEJCT id attribute value. And it works for me.